# How to differentiate cloned elements in jQuery and add events to cloned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I am trying to make deck builder. I want have this functionality, if I click on a card it shows in deck section, counter goes up. When I click on a card in deck section counter goes down and when it zero card disappears from deck section.

My problem is how to differentiate cloned elements from original and how to add event to elements I am cloning.

This is my JS script:

```
$(".bronze").mouseup(function(e){
    if (e.which === 1) {
        var counter = parseInt($(this).find(".bronze_counter").text(), 10)
        var card_name = $(this).attr("class").replace("bronze ", "")
        if (counter < 3) {
            counter += 1
            $(this).find(".bronze_counter").text(counter);
            if (counter == 1){
                $(this).clone().appendTo(".deck");
            }
            else {
                $(".deck ." + card_name).find(".bronze_counter").text(counter);
            }

        }
    }
});
```

And my template:

```
<h3>Current Deck</h3>
<div class="container deck">

</div>

<div class="container">
    {% for card in cards %}
    <span class="bronze {{ card.name | cut:'\'' | cut:' '}}">
        <span><img src="{{ card.thumbnail_link }}" style="width:5%"> [</span>
        <span class="bronze_counter">0</span>
        <span>/3] </span>
    </span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Further I need to somehow save this deck in database. I was thinking about getting card names plus counter of each card and saving them in database. Am I digging a hole under myself?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `data-` attribute on the elements that are cloned. For example:

```
<span data-cloned="true">
```

Then use or check that data:

```
$('span').data('cloned');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add an event listener to the document like this:

```
    $(document).on('click','.bronze', function(){ //stuff goes here})
```

So it basically will do the callback anytime you click on an .bronze element, so you don't need to add events for cloned elements.

If you need to save them in DB, just put them in a form and add hidden inputs for every value you need for each card.

Comment: I do not understand one thing. First I render template, then JS loads and add events to elements. Then I dynamically create (clone) elements in my HTML.
If I add event to all elements with class .bronze, will it work for new elements created (cloned) after JS loaded?

Comment: Yes, it adds an event to document itself and it checks if the element you clicked has the class .bronze

Comment: I edited my comment, still getting used to stackoverflow.

Comment: its okay, check http://api.jquery.com/on/ there is an example at the bottom with what I think you need.